# How to apply CSS style only if the last child is visible

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this issue where I need to apply some style to a div only if it's next to a visible item (even if there's non visible items in between, but not if all the items following the current one are all invisible), as shown here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3nulnw?file=style.css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.addon {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-left: none;
}

.addon.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.content:not(:last-child),
.addon:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (no addons)</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (one addon)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is shown correctly (multiple addons, one is hidden)
  </div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (multiple addons)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried looking on the internet but to no avail, but I'm probably looking for the wrong answer (most of what I found were other SO questions saying there's no CSS selector for non visible item), so alternative ways to do this are welcome (possibly without JS)

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML part in your question.

Comment: The other answers are right; you'll need to use JS/jQuery for something like this e.g. `$(element).is(":visible");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a horrible but apparently effective way of achieving what I wanted

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4hkorq?file=style.css

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.addon {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-left: none;
}

.addon.hidden {
  /* display: none; */
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
}

.content:not(:last-child),
.addon:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.container > div:last-of-type.hidden::before {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 4px;
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

.container > .addon + div:last-of-type.hidden::before {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (no addons)</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (one addon)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is shown correctly (multiple addons, one is hidden)
  </div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (multiple addons)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>
```

The trick is to use `visibility: hidden` and `width: 0` instead of `display: none`, then add a `::before` pseudo element that adds the border. It has the drawback of adding 4 pixels to the element (in order to have a 4 pixels border radius it needs to be at least 4 pixels wide) but it is acceptable in my case and (albeit with some tweaks) it also worked in my application.
For some reason I had to add `top: -1px` because it wouldn't align otherwise, but in my application I didn't need to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I try to understand your question and get this result. Please expalin more your question
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

We can get it through (:is) pseudo-class function. we can check if div has class like visible in below example case then we can apply style to its next div throught (+) adjacent sibling selector or (~) general sibling selector. I hope example will clear what I want to say

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (no addons)</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (one addon)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is shown correctly (multiple addons, one is hidden)
  </div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<!-- [ADD 'visible' CLASS BEFORE OF TARGET CONTAINER] -->
<div class="container visible">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (multiple addons)</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <div class="addon"></div>
  <div class="addon hidden"></div>
</div>
```

and its css will be

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.addon {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-left: none;
}

.addon.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.content:not(:last-child),
.addon:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0; 
}


.container:is(.visible) + .container{
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  /* Your style here */
}

.container:is(.visible) + .container .addon{
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  /* Your style here */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what i'm looking for, it's the divs with class addon that might or might not be hidden. If you see my example on stackblitz (linked in my question) I want to add rounded borders when there's no visible "addon" at the end, while remove them when there's visible addons

Comment: also, assume the containers are not next to each other in my application, they are next to each other here only to show various cases but they won't be in my real case so any change has to happen inside the "container"

Answer (score 0):

These are the major changes to CSS

> ```
> .container {display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%...}
> .addon {display: table-cell; position: relative; right: 5px; 
>        z-index: 1; padding-right: 5px;...}
> .addon+.addon {right: 10px; padding-right: 10px;...}
> .content {display: table-cell;}
> ```

Since this is a pure CSS solution, the tags were changed so that `:*-type-of` works effectively. If you want a uniform height, add a div inside `.content` and give it an absolute height (ie `px`)

```css
section:first-of-type > div {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}

section:last-of-type > div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.addon {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000000;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.addon.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.addon+.addon {
  right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (no addons)</div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (one addon)</div>
  <aside class="addon visible"></aside>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This is shown correctly (multiple addons, one is hidden)
  </div>
  <aside class="addon hidden"></aside>
  <aside class="addon visible"></aside>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <div class="content">This is shown correctly (multiple addons)</div>
  <aside class="addon visible"></aside>
  <aside class="addon visible"></aside>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <aside class="addon hidden"></aside>
</section>

<section class="container">
  <div class="content">This should have all rounded borders</div>
  <aside class="addon visible"></aside>
  <aside class="addon hidden"></aside>
</section>
```